# Can I (Xbox One) and my PS4 friend go in each other's worlds in any way?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm an avid Minecraft gamer on the Xbox One. My friend plays on the PlayStation 4. Is it possible for us to play on servers like Hypixel together? And if it is, can we go into each other's worlds if we add each other on such servers?

Also please tell me any way we can interact with each other from outside these servers. Can we use **ANY** method to go in each other's worlds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play the same world between PS4 and Mobile?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356965/how-can-i-play-the-same-world-between-ps4-and-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that good with Bedrock Edition (I mainly play java edition) and correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you should be able to join the same servers or realm. If both consoles are on the same version of Minecraft, then both of you can join the same server or join a realm together.

Answer (score 0):

To play with a friend in a server like hypixel, you can play on Mineplex and use /party and then /party invite [gamertag]. If the other person accepts the invite, you will get to the same lobby server. The /party invite command only works if your friend is also on Mineplex. Also make sure you are using the same version as your PS4 friend. Make sure it is better together or above and you 2 are on the same version. The latest version for Minecraft is 1.12.0. You will need this version to play Mineplex.